# How do I put the display logic into another function (and access object properties) without breaking?

Tags: javascript

I am learning on my own about form events and got my code working. However, I would like to break up the display logic into it's own function. Then, call that new display function in the addMovie function. I have tried this and the code breaks either saying title undefined or other errors. If I move the display logic out of the addMovie function the code breaks I think because the display function is trying to access properties of the object set in the addMovie function. How do I put the display logic into another function (and access object properties) without breaking?
[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/vYmXYBR)

```js
let movies = [];

const movieForm = document.querySelector('#movieForm');

movieForm.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // Grab user input
  const titleInput = movieForm.elements.title;
  const yrInput = movieForm.elements.year;
  // Add movie
  addMovie(titleInput, yrInput);
  // Reset form
  titleInput.value = '';
  yrInput.value = '';
});

const addMovie = (titleInput, yrInput) => {
  let newMovie = {
    id: Date.now(),
    title: titleInput.value,
    year: yrInput.value,
  };
  const {
    id,
    title,
    year
  } = newMovie;
  movies.push(newMovie);
  const displayMovie = document.createElement('li');
  displayMovie.append(`${title}, ${year}`);
  movieForm.append(displayMovie);
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movieForm {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="movieForm">
  <form action="" id="movieForm">
    <label for="movie">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <label for="year">Year: </label>
    <input type="text" name="year">
    <button id="btn">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Amith for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new function `showMovie` and pass the `newMovie` object and show the movie details

```
function showMovie({ title, year }) {
  const displayMovie = document.createElement('li');
  displayMovie.append(`${title}, ${year}`);
  movieForm.append(displayMovie);
}

// Call inside addMovie function
showMovie(newMovie);
```

```js
const movieForm = document.querySelector('#movieForm');

const movies = [];

function showMovie({ title, year }) {
  const displayMovie = document.createElement('li');
  displayMovie.append(`${title}, ${year}`);
  movieForm.append(displayMovie);
}

const addMovie = (titleInput, yrInput) => {
  let newMovie = {
    id: Date.now(),
    title: titleInput.value,
    year: yrInput.value,
  };
  movies.push(newMovie);

  // New Function
  showMovie(newMovie);
};

movieForm.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // Grab user input
  const titleInput = movieForm.elements.title;
  const yrInput = movieForm.elements.year;
  // Add movie
  addMovie(titleInput, yrInput);
  // Reset form
  titleInput.value = '';
  yrInput.value = '';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movieForm {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="movieForm">
  <form action="" id="movieForm">
    <label for="movie">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <label for="year">Year: </label>
    <input type="text" name="year">
    <button id="btn">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I see my simple mistake now. I was not passing the newMovie object in the argument of the new function. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your title will not work properly, because the `<label for="movie">Title:</label>`. "movie" does not exist. The input underneath is named title, so try to change "movie" to "title".